# Windows Server: Could not load file or assembly 'Ubiety.Dns.Core'

Tags: .net, windows-server-2012-r2

After installing my .NET application, I get:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Ubiety.Dns.Core' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)
```

The strange thing is, this happens ONLY on Windows Server 2012 R2 64-bit. On Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, it is fine.
I feel like I'm about to take a very deep dive down a very tedious rabbit hole.

Does anyone have any idea why this would trigger on Windows Server 2012?

Answer (score 0):

I updated Ubiety.Dns.Core from 2.2.2 to 4.2.2 and now it works for both.